# linux C++ issue with memory allocation

Tags: c++, arrays, linux, memory-management, heap-memory

I'm having a problem for a few days that I can resolve.
I got some old code from HPUX that i'm trying to put to work on Linux (RedHAT), and for some reason I cant use more than 2000 elements of one arry.

The array is a struct and where is definition

```
struct str_item {
         char   item [20];
         double value;
         char valueString [20];
  };
```

The arry is part of a class

```
struct str_item **dpstr_valuesCalc;
```

And in the code

```
while (dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos]) 
  {
  if (!strcmp (itemStr, dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos]->item)) return 0;
  li_pos++;
  }
   dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos] = new struct str_item;
   strcpy (dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos]->item, itemStr);
   dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos]->value = 0;
   strcpy (dpstr_valuesCalc [li_pos]->valueString, valueString);
```

And using gdb

```
while (dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos])
(gdb) p li_pos
 $38 = 2000  
 (gdb) p dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos]  <-- 
 $39 = (str_item *) 0x0            <-- No new so it's 0
 (gdb) p dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos+1]  <-- How this is something?
 $40 = (str_item *) 0x91             <-- Where this come from?
 dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos] = new struct str_item;
 (gdb) p dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos]   
 $41 = (str_item *) 0xaebd70   <-- new valide str_item
 (gdb) p dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos+1]  
 $42 = (str_item *) 0x91             <-- Still where
 strcpy (dpstr_valuesCalc [li_pos]->item, itemStr);
 dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos]->value = value;
 strcpy (dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos]->valueString, "");
(gdb) p *dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos]
$43 = {item = "Test",'\000' <repeats 15 times>, valor = 12, valorString = '\000' <repeats 19 times>}
(gdb) p *dpstr_valoresCalculados [li_pos+1]
Cannot access memory at address 0x91
```

And later on the code

```
while (dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos]) <-- in dpstr_valuesCalc [2001] is valid because (str_item *) 0x91
So it goes to 
{
  if (!strcmp (itemStr, dpstr_valuesCalc[li_pos]->item)) return 0;
And 
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
__strcmp_sse2 () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strcmp.S:213
 movlpd  (%rsi), %xmm2
```

Its seems that is a memory problem, perhaps no more heap? 
But if I understand malloc_stats there is still memory, 
system bytes-in use bytes, its right?

```
(gdb) call malloc_stats()
Arena 0:
system bytes     =    1200128
in use bytes     =    1195040
Total (incl. mmap):
system bytes     =    1814528
in use bytes     =    1809440
max mmap regions =          3
max mmap bytes   =     614400
```

Regarding the SO i think that I don't have a problem

```
ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 31192
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200  
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 4096
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

Perhaps a linker definition? must use -fPIC?

And I read this

---

13. Arrays indexing

This kind of errors is separated from the others for better structuring of the account because indexing in arrays with the usage of square brackets is just a different record of address arithmetic observed before.

Programming in C and then C++ has formed a practice to use variables of int/unsigned types in the constructions of the following kind:

```
unsigned Index = 0;
while (MyBigNumberField[Index] != id)
 Index++;
```

But time passes and everything changes. And now it's a high time to say - do not do this anymore! Use memsize types for indexing (large) arrays.

The given code won't process an array containing more than UINT_MAX items in a 64-bit program. After the access to the item with UNIT_MAX index an overflow of the Index variable will occur and we'll get infinite loop.

To persuade you entirely in the necessity of using only memsize types for indexing and in the expressions of address arithmetic, I'll give the last example

---

On http://www.viva64.com/en/a/0004/#ID0E65AM

Can this by my problem??

Any help is appreciated

Comment: It's very hard to tell what you are asking.  I'll take a shot at a meaningful comment...  You never show how space is allocated for `struct str_item **dpstr_valuesCalc;`.  Why do you expect it to have a length of 2000 or more?  Do you allocate space for 2001 pointers?